# AWS API Gateway Swagger export doesn't export models

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, swagger, aws-api-gateway

I have a deployed API in API Gateway. I want to properly document that API (including request body, differente responses, etc.)

I added models such as:

```
{
"$schema" : "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title" : "Get User Model",
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "firstName" : { "type" : "string" },
    "lastName" : { "type" : "string" },
    "email" : { "type" : "string" },
    "id" : {"type": "string"},
    "phoneNumber" : { "type" : "number" },
    "birthdayMonth" : { "type" : "number" },
    "birthdayYear" : { "type" : "number" }
  }
}
```

Then I added this model in the GET(Resource --> Method Response. I shows that it is accepted:

[image: Model in API Gateway Response]

My issue is that when I publish the documentation and then I export it to a Swagger JSON or YAML it does NOT include that model. It looks like this:

```
'/users/{id}':
    get:
      description: This endpoint retrieves a specific user.
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          description: The user id
          required: true
          type: string
      responses: {}      <-- Why is this empty???
```

There are also no models in the end of the swagger json.

What do I have to do such that my models get exported properly?